# Can not populate Record Reference Netsuite Mule connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, netsuite

I am struggling to populate a RecordRef trough Mule Netsuite connector.
Both of my solutions aren't working, any advice ?

below the code:

1)

```
        <netsuite:attribute key="entityStatus">#[groovy: new com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2013_1.RecordRef(com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2013_1.types.RecordType.CUSTOMER_STATUS,'16','16');]</netsuite:attribute>
```

**Could not find matching constructor for: com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2013_1.RecordRef(com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2013_1.types.RecordType, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)**

2)

```
  <netsuite:attribute key="category">"16"</netsuite:attribute>
```

**OR**

```
  <netsuite:attribute key="category">16</netsuite:attribute>
```

**No converter found that can convert 16 to class com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2013_1.RecordRef**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the JavaDoc for `core_2013_1` (using an old version of the connector?) but if you look at the current JavaDoc for `RecordType`:

http://mulesoft.github.io/netsuite-connector/java/com/netsuite/webservices/platform/core_2013_2/RecordRef.html

you'll see that the only contructor is a no-arg one.

So you have to instantiate the object first then call setters on it then return the object from your Groovy script. And if you're on Mule 3.4.0 or above, consider using MEL instead of Groovy.

Comment: I removed and re-installed the connector but the default endpoint is always using 2013_1, I don't now way. I also checked for updates but no one is available

Comment: I now changed my code like this :

<netsuite:attribute key="category">
 #[ ref = new com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2013_1.RecordRef();              ref.setType(com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2013_1.types.RecordType.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY());
 ref.setInternalId('6');
 ref.setEternalId('6');
return ref;    ]
</netsuite:attribute>

Comment: That's a different problem then... new question :)

Comment: true :) just double checking if my code make any sense to you